# How Run WebApplication C# in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, web-applications

I'm not sure if is possible; i have my web application development in C# on Windows.
Can i run this application on Ubuntu with vsCode? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only .Net Core runs on Linux.

You don't need an IDE to run it, there is a command for everything so you can simply open a command prompt and run everything.

Use this as a reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet

A good editor for Linux is Rider. VsCode is a glorified text editor with plugins  and if you require a proper thing then I recommend a proper code editor.

I've done some development on Ubuntu and it was very good actually, everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed dotnet-sdk then open terminal and go to project directory and
write `dotnet run` 
else write `snap install dotnet-sdk` and  `export PATH="/snap/bin/:$PATH"`
replace /snap/bin/ to your directory